# Salesforce APEX Auto Create Contact from Case

Tags: salesforce, apex

So my end goal for this project is to create a contact and a case for each customer that registers a product on my companies warranty registration page.

I have already got a python script that connects to a MySQL database and saves the needed info into an .xlsx file and then another python script currently sending that same data from the .xlsx file into salesforce and it works for a Case OR a Contact but not both. Apex trigger only works if I actually do a web-to-case or email-to-case but for some reason does not work with python.

This will be something that will be triggered roughly every 6 hours indefinitely. I already got it setup to where it does not pull the same data twice from the database so it only grabs new contacts from the MySQL database by writing a '1' to a new column in each table and does a check if '1' exists and if it does then skip it. Everything is working EXCEPT for creating a Contact AND a Case. Contact specifically because it will have all the address information we need for when a customer calls in for troubleshooting of their product, we want a case also created because that is where the product and serial numbers are taken down and allows a trigger to send the customer an email once the case has been created.

```
public class CaseAutocreateContactTest {

public static testMethod void testBulkContactsGetCreated() {
    List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        Case c = new Case(SuppliedEmail='jdoe_test_test@doe.com' + i,
                            SuppliedName='John Doe' + i,
                            Subject='Feedback - Something' + i);
        newCases.add(c);
    }
    insert newCases;

    System.debug('here');
    List<Id> newCaseIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Case caseObj:newCases) {
        newCaseIds.add(caseObj.Id);    
    }

    List<Case> updatedCases = [Select ContactId From Case Where Id in :newCaseIds];

    for (Case caseObj:updatedCases) {
        System.debug(caseObj.Id + ' ' + caseObj.ContactId);
        System.assert(caseObj.ContactId!=null,'There should be no null contacts');
    }
}

public static testMethod void testContactGetsCreated() {
    Case c = new Case(SuppliedEmail='jdoe_test_test@doe.com',
                        SuppliedName='John Doe',
                        Subject='Feedback - Something');
    insert c;

    List<Contact> johnDoes = [select Id from Contact where Email='jdoe_test_test@doe.com'];

    //there should be only 1 -- the trigger should not have created another
    System.assert(johnDoes.size()==1, 'There should be one John Doe!');

    Case caseObj = [select ContactId from Case where Id=:c.Id];
    System.assert(caseObj.ContactId!=null,'There should be no null contact on the case');
}

public static testMethod void testNoDupesAreCreated() {
    Contact cnt1 = new Contact(FirstName = 'John',
                            LastName = 'Doe',
                            Email='jdoe_test_test@doe.com');

    insert cnt1;

    Case case1 = new Case(SuppliedEmail='jdoe_test_test@doe.com',
                        SuppliedName='John Doe',
                        Subject='Feedback - Something');

    insert case1;

    List<Contact> johnDoes = [select Id from Contact where Email='jdoe_test_test@doe.com'];

    //there should be only 1 -- the trigger should not have created another
    System.assert(johnDoes.size()==1, 'There should be only one John Doe!');
}

public static testMethod void testEmailNameDoesntGetCreated() {
    Case c = new Case(SuppliedEmail='testEmailNameDoesntGetCreated@doe.com',
                        SuppliedName='testEmailNameDoesntGetCreated@doe.com',
                        Subject='Feedback - Something');
    insert c;

    List<Contact> johnDoes = [select Id from Contact where Email='testEmailNameDoesntGetCreated@doe.com'];

    //there should be only 1 -- the trigger should not have created another
    System.assert(johnDoes.size()==0, 'There should be no John Does!');
}
}
```

Comment: I am confused by your question.  Are you trying to get your test methods to work with the data that already exists in your database or are you asking why the trigger doesn't work when it isn't being fired by a test method.  Could you please provide the trigger code or some additional context?  If you want your test method to have access to your existing Contacts/Cases, you need to add the "@isTest(SeeAllData=true)" flag [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm]

Comment: So the test class above works with the trigger but only works when a case was created with jdoe_test_test@doe.com, John Doe and subject is Feedback - Something. I am trying to make it to where the trigger works for all cases with SuppliedEmail filled in and not just a test one with those predefined variable of John Doe.         I got the trigger and class from : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Autocreating_Contacts_From_Web_To_Case

Comment: Ok.  So are you saying that only the test class works or only the trigger works when the case has the email address jdoe_test_test@doe.com and name as John Doe?  The trigger code is completely agnostic of the input.  What is your testing method for a case that has a different email address?

Comment: Well I am sure if I change the SuppliedEmail to something else in the test class then it would work as well. But the issue I am having is making the trigger work without the test class and with predefined info. I have a python script creating cases automatically but need a way for salesforce to create a contact for that web-to-case. I am assuming the Test Class ALWAYS has to be there for the trigger to work or can the trigger work standalone somehow? I am just trying to make it to where the Test Class is not specific to John Doe and his email address and case subject

Comment: Python script... so the case creation is being done via a Rest transaction?

Comment: Yes, using Simple-Salesforce. My end goal is to create a case then a contact for that case or vise versa but it seems there are restrictions with Simple-Salesforce and won't do both, just one or the other so I am looking for other means of creating a Contact from a Case or creating a Case from a Contact.

Comment: I recall having a very similar problem with inserts from Simple-Salesforce.  It was over a year ago, but I think I discovered that Simple-Salesforce's create and upsert weren't firing the trigger.  Sadly, I don't have my testbed set up to throw some code at it nor could I find a documented case stating that Simple-Salesforce won't fire the trigger.  I would recommend two things.  First, try sending a email to your Email-To-Case address to confirm whether or not it will generate a Contact (make sure you don't exist as a contact first).  Second, update the trigger to just print to debug and test

Comment: You nailed it. It is the python script that is causing it to not work. Tried Web-To-Case method and it worked fine for any case I created. Why would the python script cause it to not work? That doesn't make sense to me. It should be working for ANY case created with SuppliedName, SuppliedEmail being used you would think.

Comment: There are "features" in Salesforce's trigger handling rules.  The one that gets me are that triggers on Attachment Insert are not fired if the attachment is created via an email sent from Salesforce.  I needed that trigger to fire for a security check and it simply didn't work.

Comment: What if I used some html from web-to-case and incorporated it into the python script, or send the data from current python script to the html file for web to case? Does python allow this?

Comment: Could you better describe your end goal?  The issue we were tackling was "why won't the trigger fire?"  What was never discussed was your end goal.  What is the size and scope of your data set?  What do you want the end result to be?  Is this a one time process (data migration or initial data import) or an ongoing process (something to happen with all new cases generated)?  Describe the workflow you want.  You may have to edit your question or post a new one to add all of the content.

Comment: I updated the initial question with more details of what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

So I first created a Contact like I already had working with Simple-Salesforce and then used Selenium package in Python to open web-to-case html file hosted locally and send the data from the .xlsx sheet and submit. Confirmed it creates a case for each customer in .xlsx sheet and confirmed salesforce associates the contact and case with one another.